# What is the complexity of this algorithm? (java)

Tags: java, string, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

The while loop is `O(logn)`. Will the inner loop do `O(n)` work since it will concatenate n characters max (resulting in `O(logn + n)` in total)? Would using a StringBuilder make it `O(1)`?

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
// some code to add N items to l
//.
//.
//.
while (l.size() > 1) {
    int lo = 0, hi = l.size() - 1;
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    while (lo < hi) {
        temp.add("(" + l.get(lo) + "," + l.get(hi) + ")");
        lo++;
        hi--;
    }
    l = temp;
}
```

Comment: @Strom What? What does O(2) even mean? Now, I might not be the most experienced person in programming, but I did give enough attention in my Data structures and algorithms class to understand that there's no such thing as O(2), or O(3), or O(60) for that matter (and so on). Big-O is used to describe the performance or complexity of an algorithm. It's not an actual timer.

Comment: @Strom The code above could not be evaluated to O(1) or any other constant/fixed time. The size of the list determines most runtime here, resulting in both the outer loop and the inner loop being O(N). And since String concatenation itself is O(N) here, we get O(N*N*N) = O(N^3).

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with multiple solutions the best one outputting a string is a modification of your original post.

This solution would match the algorithmic time of using StringBuilder(l.size * 2 -1).  The `* 2 - 1` is to allow for the commas.

The following solution reduces the inner loop to O(1), by pre-allocating the array list with the maximum number of elements, each of which can be directly assigned. Your original code required a deep copy of all of the elements of the arraylist, resulting in a time of O(N) to add a new element, **beyond initial capacity** of the arraylist. The following code initializes the array list to the proper size.

The entire complexity is 1/2 * N  + (1/2 * (N - 1) + (1/4 * (N - 2)) + (1/8 * (N -3))...)

My math/analysis may not be correct, however, the lower bound is given that the string concatenation of all elements of an array requires at minimum N operations => O(N)
The upper bound, assuming my math is correct above, is also O(N). Since anything  less than half of a value can not added to a value to make the total above the original value.

If my math is wrong the worst case is N log N.

The absolute upper bound is N squared(if you ignore the fact N decreases every iteration).

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
// some code to add N items to l
//.
//.
//.
while (l.size() > 1) {
    int lo = 0, hi = l.size() - 1;
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>(l.size/2 + 1);
    while (lo < hi) {
        temp.add("(" + l.get(lo) + "," + l.get(hi) + ")");
        lo++;
        hi--;
    }
    l = temp;
}
```

In practice, the allocation and de-allocation of memory of 1/2 N ArrayLists for all but small to medium values of N, becomes the limiting factor of the algorithm.